# Excel JavaScript Apis call class function with event handler from command

Tags: javascript, excel, typescript, office-js, excel-addins

I am trying to add and remove event handler for `onSelectionChanged`.

If I defined the functions like below with `export async function`

```
export async function EnableCellHighlight(): Promise<void> {
  console.log(1);
  let _this: any = this;
    await Excel.run(async function(context){
        let workbook = context.workbook;
        workbook.onSelectionChanged.add(CellHighlightHandler);
        await context.sync();
    });
}
export async function CellHighlightHandler(event: Excel.SelectionChangedEventArgs): Promise<void>{
  await Excel.run(async (context) => {
      let workbook = context.workbook;
      let sheets = workbook.worksheets;
      sheets.load("items");
      await context.sync();
      // clear previous meekou conditional format
      await clearMeekouFormat();
      // add new conditional format
      let selection = workbook.getSelectedRange();
      selection.load("rowIndex,columnIndex");
      await context.sync();
      let rowConditionalFormat = selection.getEntireRow().conditionalFormats.add(Excel.ConditionalFormatType.custom);
      rowConditionalFormat.custom.format.fill.color = "red";
      rowConditionalFormat.custom.rule.formula = `=ROW()= + ${(selection.rowIndex + 1)} + N("${AppConsts.Meekou}")`;
      let columnConditionalFormat = selection.getEntireColumn().conditionalFormats.add(Excel.ConditionalFormatType.custom);
      columnConditionalFormat.custom.format.fill.color = "red";
      columnConditionalFormat.custom.rule.formula = `=Column()= + ${(selection.columnIndex + 1)} + N("${AppConsts.Meekou}")`;
      await context.sync();
  });
}

export async function clearMeekouFormat(): Promise<void> {
  await Excel.run(async function (context) {
    let workbook = context.workbook;
    let worksheets = workbook.worksheets;
    worksheets.load("items/name");
    await context.sync();
    for (let i = 0; i < worksheets.items.length; i++) {
      let worksheet = worksheets.items[i];
      let conditionalFormats = worksheet.getRange().conditionalFormats;     
      conditionalFormats.load("items/type");
      await context.sync();
      let total = conditionalFormats.items.length;
      for(let j = total-1; j >=0; j --){
        let conditionalFormat = conditionalFormats.items[j];
        if(conditionalFormat.type == Excel.ConditionalFormatType.custom){
          conditionalFormat.load("custom/rule/formula");
          await context.sync();
          if (conditionalFormat.custom.rule.formula.includes(AppConsts.Meekou)) {
            conditionalFormat.delete();
          }
        }              
      }            
    }      
    await context.sync();
  });
}
```

It will works correctly.

But, if I move above code to a class like below:

```
export class ExcelService {
private cellHighlightHandler = this.CellHighlightHandler;

//#region excel events
    async enableCellHighlight(): Promise<void> {
      console.log(1);
      let _this: any = this;
        await Excel.run(async function(context){
            let workbook = context.workbook;
            workbook.onSelectionChanged.add(_this.cellHighlightHandler);
            await context.sync();
        });
    }
    async disableCellHightlight(): Promise<void> {
      let _this: any = this;
        await this.clearMeekouFormat();
        await Excel.run(async function(context){
            let workbook = context.workbook;
            workbook.onSelectionChanged.remove(_this.cellHighlightHandler);
            await context.sync();
        });        
    }
    async CellHighlightHandler(event: Excel.SelectionChangedEventArgs): Promise<void>{
      let _this: ExcelService = this;
        await Excel.run(async (context) => {
            let workbook = context.workbook;
            let sheets = workbook.worksheets;
            sheets.load("items");
            await context.sync().catch(e => console.log(e));
            // clear previous meekou conditional format
            await _this.clearMeekouFormat().catch(e => console.log(e));
            // add new conditional format
            let selection = workbook.getSelectedRange();
            selection.load("rowIndex,columnIndex");
            await context.sync();
            let rowConditionalFormat = selection.getEntireRow().conditionalFormats.add(Excel.ConditionalFormatType.custom);
            rowConditionalFormat.custom.format.fill.color = "red";
            rowConditionalFormat.custom.rule.formula = `=ROW()= + ${(selection.rowIndex + 1)} + N("${AppConsts.Meekou}")`;
            let columnConditionalFormat = selection.getEntireColumn().conditionalFormats.add(Excel.ConditionalFormatType.custom);
            columnConditionalFormat.custom.format.fill.color = "red";
            columnConditionalFormat.custom.rule.formula = `=Column()= + ${(selection.columnIndex + 1)} + N("${AppConsts.Meekou}")`;
            await context.sync();
        });
    }
    /**
     * clear all meekou conditional format
     */
    async clearMeekouFormat(): Promise<void> {
        await Excel.run(async function (context) {
          let workbook = context.workbook;
          let worksheets = workbook.worksheets;
          worksheets.load("items/name");
          await context.sync();
          for (let i = 0; i < worksheets.items.length; i++) {
            let worksheet = worksheets.items[i];
            let conditionalFormats = worksheet.getRange().conditionalFormats;     
            conditionalFormats.load("items/type");
            await context.sync();
            let total = conditionalFormats.items.length;
            for(let j = total-1; j >=0; j --){
              let conditionalFormat = conditionalFormats.items[j];
              if(conditionalFormat.type == Excel.ConditionalFormatType.custom){
                conditionalFormat.load("custom/rule/formula");
                await context.sync();
                if (conditionalFormat.custom.rule.formula.includes(AppConsts.Meekou)) {
                  conditionalFormat.delete();
                }
              }              
            }            
          }      
          await context.sync();
        });
      }

//#endregion
}
```

The code will run stop  `await _this.clearMeekouFormat().catch(e => console.log(e));`, but it did not throw any error

Comment: That handler defines _this with `let _this: ExcelService = this;` instead of `let _this: any = this;` as your other methods do. Could that be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have tried to remove the "catch(...)", like what you called in the first sample code "await _this.clearMeekouFormat();", Function "clearMeekouFormat(...)" actually does not have return expected promise?